# Show $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod\left(1+\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right) = e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx}$ where $f(x)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, integration, infinite-product

I need to show: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod\left(1+\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right) = e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx}$$

My attempt:

> $\lim_{n \to \infty}[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n}))-\log(e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx})= 0 $
>
> $\lim_{n \to \infty}[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n}))-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx]= 0 $
>
> $\lim_{n \to \infty}[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n}))-\log(e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})})]= 0 $
>
> $\lim_{n \to \infty}[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})}{e^{\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})dx}})] = \lim_{n \to \infty}\log((\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{1}{n})}{e^{\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{1}{n})}}))+\cdots+\lim_{n \to \infty}\log((\frac{1+\frac{k}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})}{e^{\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})}}))+ \cdots + \lim_{n \to \infty}\log((\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{n}{n})}{e^{\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{n}{n})}})) \cdots (1)$
>
> (Since $\log(x)$ is a continuous function) $\lim_{n \to \infty}log((\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})}{e^{\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})}})) = log(\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1+\frac{k}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})}{e^{\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})}}))$
>
> We know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})\to 0$
>
> Hence it is of the form $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x} = 1$
>
> Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n}))= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(1) = 0$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Any conditions on $f(x)$? $\log$ function can't be applied to anything!

Comment: When you convert the integral to Riemann sums, it is wrong to keep the $dx$ around.

Comment: The key problem is that you can’t bring the limit into the sum, because the limit is $\sum_{k=1}^n,$ so $n$ doesn’t make sense outside the limit. For example, you expect Riemann sum terms to individually go to zero, but the number of terms increase, so not all integrals are zero.

Comment: Use $$
\log (1 + x) = x + \mathcal{O}(x^2 ), \qquad x \to 0.
$$

Comment: If I were you I would avoid to write things like "$\lim \cdots = \lim \cdots = \lim \cdots$' but instead I would choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$, do the calculations for the finite sum / product until $n$ (which does make sense) and then conclude the existence of such a limit.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836138/help-finding-the-limit-of-lim-n-to-infty-prod-k-1n-left1-frac1n

Comment: I just corrected a few things. Does this look better now?

Comment: @rtybase One could argue like this: Since $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, it's bounded. So for $n$ big enough $1+\frac{1}{n} f(\frac{k}{n})$ is positive. Of course, this should be included in the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing from the 3. line onwards (the sum is in the exponent, not term-wise), but starting with the second line and assuming finiteness of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ and $n$ being large you can estimate the following $$\sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\,f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left[ \frac{1}{n}\,f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) + O\left(1/n^2\right) \right] \\ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) + O(1/n) \, .$$

Comment: How do you prove that $\log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$

Comment: @ThirstForMaths By using Taylor expansion of $x \mapsto \log (1+x)$ near $x=0$.

Comment: A key is that a fixed constant can be used for the $O(1/n^2)$ for all $k.$ You get this, for example, if $f$ is bounded. If it was a different constant for each $k,$ this wouldn’t necessarily work.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t go from $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n$ to $\sum_{k=1}^n\lim_{n\to\infty},$ because the number of terms in the sum depends on $n.$ The sum doesn’t even make sense outside the limit, because there is no value of $n$ there.

In particular, all Riemann integrals would be zero if you could do this. If $f(x)$ is bounded on $[0,1],$ then  $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx =\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1nf(k/n)$$ But since $f$ is bounded, $\frac1nf(k/n)\to 0$ for any $k.$

So your argument would give us zero for all Riemann integrals.

As a commenter noted, use that $\log(1+x)=x+O(x^2),$ for $|x|<1.$

One way get a limit of zero for $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k}\tag1$$ is to show the terms satisfy $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\max_{k\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}} |a_{n,k}|=0$$ for all $k.$

In your case: $$a_{n,k}=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$

---

Another approach is to use the dominated convergence theorem.

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,k}= 0$ for all $k,$ and $b_k$ is a sequence such that $|a_{n,k}|\leq b_k$ for all $k,n,$ and $\sum b_k<+\infty,$ then (1) converges to $0$.